# What does the pub(crate) function declaration syntax mean? When is it used?

Tags: rust

I am a rust newbie and I came across this kind of function declaration in an open source [repository](https://github.com/bodil/palmtree/blob/master/src/search.rs) `pub(crate) fn`

I have never seen this kind of syntax before so I was wondering what is it used for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It defines the level of visibility. The levels of visibility (privacy) are explained [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html):

> Syntax
>   Visibility :
>         pub
>      | pub ( crate )
>      | pub ( self )
>      | pub ( super )
>      | pub ( in SimplePath )
>
> pub(in path) makes an item visible within the provided path. path must be a parent module of the item whose visibility is being declared.
>
> pub(crate) makes an item visible within the current crate.
>
> pub(super) makes an item visible to the parent module. This is equivalent to pub(in super).
>
> pub(self) makes an item visible to the current module. This is equivalent to pub(in self).

So `pub(crate) fn find_key<K, S>(keys: &Chunk<K, S>, key: &K) -> Option<usize>` makes the `find_key` function public (available for use) within the crate, but not outside of it.